# How do I lower clock speed for MKR1000?

Tags: mkr1000, speed

According to [data sheets](http://k12stem.us/assets/Arduino%20Board%20Lineup%20v2.pdf), the MKR1000 runs a SAMD21 Cortex-M0+ processor at 48 MHz. For a project I need to drop that down to 16MHz to get some accurate timing in us. How can I do this? Most of the suggestions on the internet involve the ATmega* boards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because I'm interfacing with external hardware that can only handle 16MHz.

Comment: add the comment about interfacing 16MHz to your question, then delete your comment. ... replace the `to get some accurate timing in us` with the reference to external hardware .... i am deleting my comments.

Answer (score 2):

48 MHz is a multiple of 16MHz. Why not just adjust the timing code to account?

Comment: As noted above, I am not certain this will work, because I'm interfacing with some external hardware whose max speed is 16MHz. I'm trying to slow down for that. Maybe I need some artificial delays inserted, then?

Comment: Elaborate on your external hardware, then.